# data array empty after redux-saga

Tags: redux-saga

so far I couldn't figure out why is that I'm not getting data from the fetch using redux-saga, I don't know why  the data array is empty after the promise resolves.

here is my code :

```
    function* getListFromApi() {
    const response = fetch(listUrl, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: '',
    });
    console.log(response, 'response')

    const list = yield response.status === 200 ? JSON.parse(response._bodyInit): []    
    console.log(list,'list')   
    return list;
}

       export const Api = {
        getListFromApi
    };
```

/appointmentsSaga.js

```
    function* fetchList() {
    try {
        const list = yield Api.getListFromApi();   
        yield put({ type: FETCH_SUCCESS, list: list });     
    } catch (error) {        
        yield put({ type: FETCH_FAIL, error });
    }
}
export function* watchFetchList() {
    yield takeLatest(FETCH_APPOINTMENTS, fetchList);
}
```

the console.log(response) gives :

```
    Promise {_40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null}
_40: 0
_55: Response
headers: Headers {map: {…}}
ok: true
status: 200
statusText: undefined
type: "default"
url: //listUrl
_bodyBlob: Blob {_data: {…}}
_bodyInit: Blob {_data: {…}}
__proto__: Object
_65: 1
_72: null
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not waiting for the promise to resolve anywhere, so this code zips by before the fetch has completed. In a saga, you can `yield` a promise and redux saga will wait for the promise to resolve, and then resume your saga.

Also, when using the fetch api you'll need to use `.json()` (or one of the other methods if you're not dealing with json data) to get access to the data in the message. This returns a promise too, so you'll need to wait for that.

```
function* getListFromApi() {
  const response = yield fetch(listUrl, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: '',
  });

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw response.status;
  }

  const data = yield response.json();

  return data;
}
```